# The deferred antipattern, how to handle rejects?

Tags: angularjs, angular-promise

I understand what is [The deferred antipattern](https://github.com/petkaantonov/bluebird/wiki/Promise-anti-patterns#the-deferred-anti-pattern), also mentioned as "The Forgotten Promise" [HERE](http://taoofcode.net/promise-anti-patterns/).

I also read: [what-is-the-explicit-promise-construction-antipattern-and-how-do-i-avoid-it](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23803743/what-is-the-explicit-promise-construction-antipattern-and-how-do-i-avoid-it).

Anyways I should try to get rid of using `$q.defer()`.

But I don't understand how to handle case where I got response and I need to reject it because it doesn't have proper key.

This is my method in Service that returns promise to controller.

```
self.findTime = function(data){

  var deferred = $q.defer();

   apiClient.findTime(data)
      .then(function (response) {

         if (response.result !== "success") {
            deferred.reject(response);
         }

        deferred.resolve(response);
      }
      , function (error) {
      deferred.reject(error);
        console.error(error);
      });

      return deferred.promise;
};
```

So I tried to change it to:

```
self.findTime = function(data){      

   return apiClient.findTime(data)
      .then(function (response) {

         if (response.result !== "success") {
            // return WHAT ??? <-------------
         }
        return response;
      }
      , function (error) {
      // return WHAT ??? <-------------
        console.error(error);
   });
};
```

How to handle `reject`?

In controller, on reject  I show some morning message.

```
 Service.findTime(data).then(function (response) {
   // do something
    }, function (error) {
      // show warn dialog
 });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have two options.

You can return a rejection promise from within your resolve:

```
return apiClient.findTime(data)
    .then(function (response) {
        if (response.result !== "success") {
            return $q.reject('reason'); // Convert to rejection
        }
        return response;
    }, function (error) {
        console.error(error);
        return $q.reject('reason');  // Chain rejection
    });
```

or you can throw an exception:

```
return apiClient.findTime(data)
    .then(function (response) {
        if (response.result !== "success") {
            throw new Error('reason');
        }
        return response;
    }, function (error) {
        console.error(error);
        throw new Error(error);
    });
```